# 'Join Attribute by Location (Summary)' slows down with time

Tags: qgis, attribute-joins, spatial-join, speed

I'm attempting to perform a **'Join Attribute by Location (Summary)'** between **two polygon layers** where I calculate the **sum** of a given field in the join layer using the **'Intersect' predicate**. The process however seems extremely slow and it actually seems to be slowing down with time to the point of it being unusable.

The input layer has a feature count of 1,907,160 and the join layer has a feature count of 6,042,342. A sample visualization is given below (input layer are the brown rectangles):

[image: Polygon layers to be joined]

Both layers have spatial indexes created. Wondering if there's a way to speed up the process. I've also added the current log file below:

[image: Log]

Answer (score 0):

Probably joining and creating the sum at once is too much for such large layers. Split up the process: 1) join 2) sum.

An alternative would be using this expression - however, I fear that you will hit the same limits:

```
array_sum(overlay_intersects ('building', value))
```

So first select the grid cells that have an intersection from the other layer (I call it `buildings`) with Select by expression and this expression: `overlay_intersects ('building')`. Try running `Join Attribute by Location (Summary)` for the selected features only.

Otherwise, create a new field called `list` that returns a list of the values from the overlapping polygons: `overlay_intersects ('building', value)` and use datatype: `Decimal (real) list`. In the last step, create another field to create the sum: `array_sum(list)`.

However, consider that if a building overlaps more then one cell, its value will be calculated several times for each cell as can be seen in this screenshot:

[image]